# Result inconsistencies between solvers in CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, coin-or-cbc

I am running an LP optimization using `CVXPY` and testing a number of solvers. Previously, when running the same mathematical formulation of my problem I received consistent results, regardless of which solver used `(Gurobi, CBC, or ECOS)`. Since middle of 2021, the results with ECOS have maintained consistency but the other solvers have discrepancies.

For example, I am solving a power distribution problem where the results provide the dispatch of power generators throughout an operating horizon.

Previous Result (and with current ECOS)

```
G1 = [0,0,0,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Current Result

```
G1 = [0,0,0,140,140,140,140,0,140,140,140,140,140,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

[image: Graphical Result Comparison]

When I add a penalty to my objective function in order to avoid this behaviour, solve times go up quite substantially (5x).

My questions is whether anyone has seen similar behaviour and found a solution.

Comment: If both solutions satisfy the constraints and optimality tolerances then they may well both be acceptable. In other words, is it possible that your problem has many solutions which are almost just as good? Is it really an LP or a MILP?

Comment: The solutions between different solvers have always remained consistent (i.e. within an acceptable tolerance), I am minimizing the cost of operation. My question is more around the variables that are decided to get to the solution, and consistency between time steps. The drop off at time 16 and 26 in the above graph have not happened previously.